# Are there modern Fender Telecasters with the dark circuit?

Tags: electric-guitar

Are there modern Fender tellies with the dark circuit? I saw this video that demonstrates an old Fender Tele with the dark circuit, was wondering if there are modern examples that don't require a second mortgage on your house to buy.

Comment: This is not a recommendation for gear question!

Comment: I think at least one person sees this as a gear recommendation question. Might be better to reach out to a music instrument retailer with this question. For here, maybe if explain what kind of answer you’re looking for it would help. Like just a yes or no answer?

Comment: I'm asking about the features of a guitar. This question can be answered definitively by someone who knows the Fender catalog better than I do.

Comment: Or just browsing the fender web site. If you’re asking about the features of a guitar, you’ll want to specify which guitar. “Telecaster” is not specific enough.

Comment: Made an edit to clarify I specifically interested in Fender guitars not any other brands T-Shaped guitar.

Comment: An email direct to Fender would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one, or you can modify a telecaster to install a dark circuit. Many such aftermarket mods are available as pre-wired switch plates. Whether you would need a second mortgage on your house to buy what I found for modern built telecasters with vintage dark wiring, I don’t know. I didn’t find any that I would consider easily affordable. I think buying an affordable tele and then modifying it is probably a better way to go unless you are ok spending a lot.

The nocaster wiring, especially the dark circuit part of it, is not very popular at all. I played it once and personally didn’t find it usable.

You might search for “nocaster circuit” or “51 nocaster circuit” or “51 circuit telecaster” in addition to searching for “dark circuit” if you want to find specific products.

Comment: Although I don't know the full details of the differences, I would suspect that the pickups in a modern Tele are not identical to the vintage instruments.  There are significant interactions between the pickup and tone control circuit, so adding a copy of the original "dark circuit" to a modern Tele may not give the same result.  A pre-wired mod would be best if it is designed for a particular vintage of pickup.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather from here this seems to be a something like a switch that probably switches between the regular tone knob and a direct capacitor bridged to ground.

I guess you have multiple options. You could potentially simply replace the cap on your tone pot with one with a larger capacity, decreasing the lowpass frequency of that filter. This would be useful if you do not actually use the tone pot a lot. You could also install a switch and use it to have one position go directly to output with a cap bridged in to ground.

Else you might try to find a suitable trimmer cap to get a variable tone cap. You may also simply install a push pull pot as for example you tone pot to either create a switch like in the previously mentioned way, or to have the tone pot routed through different caps depending on position, allowing you to switch between a "dark" tone mode and "normal" tone mode.